# Linq: additional parameter

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following line:

```
orderBaseData.Single(o => o.Id == order.Id).OrderMessages.Count;
```

I want to filter this a bit more. Each OrderMessage has a variable called hideFromUser, and I want to get the count of the OrderMessages where this is set to FALSE only.

Thanks in advance,

Bob

Comment: `orderBaseData.Single(o => o.Id == order.Id).OrderMessages.Count(om => !om.hideFromUser);`

Comment: If this query is against database (if you use Entity Framework or other ORM tool for example) - you better use something like `orderBaseData.Where(o => o.Id == order.Id).SelectMany(o => o.OrderMessages).Where(m => !m.hideFromUser).Count()` to perform just one query to the database.

Comment: @Evk this would not actually enforce the `Single` constraint.

Comment: @grek40 while true, in almost all cases `Single` constraint is not needed anyway. For example I bet in this case order table has unique index on order id (there should be such index anyway), so query cannot return more than one order.

Comment: Is this entity framework or linq to objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Where on OrderMessages

```
orderBaseData
  .Single(o => o.Id == order.Id)
  .OrderMessages
     .Where(x => !x.hideFromUser)
     .Count();
```

Comment: You could compress this a bit by writing the predictate in the count statement: `orderBaseData.Single(o => o.Id == order.Id).OrderMessages.Count(x => !x.hideFromUser);`

Answer (score 0):

In order to retrieve the data efficiently in a single query, instead of relying on LazyLoading the OrderMessages afterwards, you could use the following:

```
orderBaseData
    .Where(o => o.Id == order.Id)
    .Select(o => o.OrderMessages.Where(x => !x.hideFromUser).Count())
    .Single();
```

This approach is mostly interesting when orderBaseData is some `IQueryable` targeting a database. If all the data are already in memory, then it is not really better or worse than the other approaches.

Comment: It stands to reason that filtering on an ID field returns a single object, not multiple objects. This is implicitly confirmed by OP's use of `.Single()`. I don't understand why you've changed the `.Single()` in the question to a `.Where()`, I don't see any justification for this. This is making the rest of your answer needlessly complicated without any discernible benefit to it.

Comment: @Flater I filter before `Select`, because otherwise I would need to keep the `Id` in the selected properties. This way, I can select the count as only value - which is not really suitable as filter in the `Single`.

Comment: What is the point of using a `.Where()` when you are **sure** that your filtering will only yield a single result? You are needlessly wrapping that one result in an IEnumerable. My point is that **you don't even need the `Select()` statement at all**. Your answer in unnecessarily contrived. Counter suggestion: `orderBaseData.Single(o => o.Id == order.Id).OrderMessages.Where(x => !x.hideFromUser).Count()`. I've simply removed the unnecessary IEnumerable wrapping and its consequences.

Comment: The result of `Single` is not `IQuerable` so I believe that this answer is trying to make the query in such a way that only one SQL statement will be generated and that all the filtering will be done there.

Comment: You have no way of knowing whether this filtering is occurring on the database or in memory. It is not part of the question.

Comment: @Flater *"You have no way of knowing whether this filtering is occurring on the database or in memory"* care to prove your claim? Your approach would surely happen in memory, mine should work server side (ofcourse if it's querying the database at all).

Comment: How do you expect me to prove a negative?

Comment: If the op is querying the database this answer would be the best way to go about it.

Comment: @Flater it's possibly a misunderstanding. I was reading it as if I wouldn't know where the code is executed (even in case its a database query) while you meant the question is not telling what kind of datasource is involved. My point is, as long as we don't know the data source, a solution that will perform well with both, memory and sql, is justified even when the code is a little bit more complicated than a memory only answer.